# SQL - Is it possible to use alias in where?

Tags: sql

I tried the following SQL on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_alias_column0) example playground page from W3Schools.

```
SELECT CustomerID AS Id, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers
WHERE Customer="Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

But I get `No value given for one or more required parameters.` as response.
It works if I use `CustomerName` instead of the alias.

Is this a fail of the playground test page or is it just not possible?

Comment: the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before `select`. Hence the `where` clause is not aware of the aliases you used.

Comment: no  ... in where condition the alias are not allowed

Comment: I tried the snippet from the question and it works on the playground page linked to.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the browser since the DB is created in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before select. Hence the where clause is not aware of the aliases you used.

So you need to use the original column name:

```
SELECT CustomerID AS Id, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName="Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

If you must use alias in the where clause, you may use subquery or CTE (an overkill and may result in slower query):

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT CustomerID AS Id, CustomerName AS Customer
    FROM Customers
) t WHERE Customer = "Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

Comment: to use the alias "customer" in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code:

```
SELECT CustomerID AS Id, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers
WHERE Customer="Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

To alias the customer table you can do something like:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID AS Id, c.CustomerName AS Customer
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE c.CustomerName="Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

Where c is now the alias for Customers

It is not possible to use a column alias in a where clause because the where clause executes BEFORE the select.

Comment: I think they meant if column aliases could be used, not table ones.  But correct otherwise.

Comment: Gotcha, updated answer

Comment: Yes Timothy G. is right, but still thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ugly, but can be convenient in larger, more complex queries

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT CustomerID AS ID, CustomerName AS Customer
FROM Customers) as A

WHERE Customer = "Alfreds Futterkiste";
```

Comment: Especially if you are going to need that reference more than once in the rest of the query

Answer (score 1):

No you can't reference the column alias in the WHERE clause.